# Amplify Finance tracking system design

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

new to AWS and Cloud Architecting in general. i have a question. i was working on an lab project for myself. me and some of my friends have a non profit do so some flood relief and other related activities in my country

Guys were using a very basic app written with Node and Mongo to track donations received and what “Cause” the donation was for. And similarly expenses incurred etc etc

It was a very simple App that just used a web form to add transaction with various attributes such as “Cause” (flood Relief, Poverty Alleviation etc etc)

And the app would allow you to record the donation.. an HTML form and then also show the TOTAL balance overall and Balance per “Cause” etc etc

As a challenge to myself i am rewriting that app on AWS and using Amplify. I have successfully modeled everything and have a working NextJS app hosted on Amplify Hosting. The App uses Amplify Auth, API and Storage.

I am facing a challenge. the old app whenever you query for TOTAL balance would just get all transactions from the DB and just do addition/subtraction (donations recvd / Expenses Incurred) from the 1st transactions :slightly_smiling_face: . This would not be a good idea on the Cloud and also if the system Grew too much, counting the balance from All the transactions etc doesn't scale well IMHO.

I need to DESIGN a much more better system. In. my head many diff mecanisms come

1. Count the Total of all transactions per "Cause" at midnight by running a lambda function and have it store data in a Seperate DynmaoDB table for that cause
2. Whenever a Txn is made in DymaoDB. Add it to a SQS queue and trigger a Lambda to just update the Balance of that cause in the DymamoDB table

or any other approach which you folks suggest is best fit for this.

Note that i have a Model called Transactions and it stores all transaction in a flat format

```
type Txn @model {
  id: ID!
  amount: Float!
  txnType: TxnType!
  comment: String
  DestCause: Cause @hasOne
  Donors: Donors @hasOne
  tags: [String]
}

type Cause @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

One approach that comes to my mind is to have the balance information in the cause itself and update it whenever a transaction is made

```
type Txn @model {
  id: ID!
  amount: Float!
  txnType: TxnType!
  comment: String
  DestCause: Cause @hasOne
  Donors: Donors @hasOne
  tags: [String]
}

type Cause @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  balance: Float!
}
```